# How to Display Your Guild Emblem? (Guild Armorer)

Tags: guild-wars-2

After researching the 'Guild Armor Contract' and 'Guild Emblem Template', you're presented with the option of purchasing Guild Armor as shown below:

NOTE: This particular vendor is located in WvW spawn location.

[image: Such as this vendor on the WvW Battlegrounds]

Can someone explain how this works? Is it a once-per-armor item? Will it remain with a transmute? etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consumable item, and therefore has a one-time use.

It works the same as transmuting, you change a piece of armor to look like another. In this case, you are changing a piece of heavy armor to display the guild emblem.

Comment: Correct. Which means you can only display a guild emblem on "Guild Armor", instead of any old piece of equipment